# how to modify the pagination rules by WP_Query?

Tags: pagination

I want to do the pagination for my custom post type "Employes", but if I use the WP_Query, I can use the attribute post_per_page, but the URL changed like this.../page/2. I want the URL changes by this way ...#2, because the former way I can't use tab content, Who can help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```html
function custom_pagination_base() {
 global $wp_rewrite;

 $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = '{pagination-url-here}';

 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_pagination_base' );
```

Paste this code in theme function.php
{pagination-url-here} replace your uri segment